# Always resolve type in new Lifetimescope?

Tags: autofac

Is there a way to make Autofac to always resolve types in a new lifetimescope?

ie.

```
Container.Resolve<MyHandler>().Whatever();
```

Now i have to do like this:

```
Container.BeginLifetimeScope().Resolve<MyHandler>().Whatever();
```

It would be nice to be able to inject MyHandler into a class and know that MyHandler is it own scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Autofac does not provide a way to automatically start a new lifetime scope per component resolution.**

Creating a lifetime scope is actually a process you need to control **very tightly**. Lifetime scopes not only help the scoping of component resolution, but also manage the deterministic disposal of components you resolve. From a memory management perspective, you shouldn't just fire up lifetime scopes without also disposing of them when you're done. **Failing to dispose your created scopes can very easily cause a memory leak.**

This is why you *always* see `BeginLifetimeScope` in a `using` statement or in a very tightly integrated scenario like ASP.NET request lifetime - so you can start a scope at a known spot and be sure to end/dispose of it. Child lifetime scopes are not automatically disposed for you once they're created - it's up to you to do that cleanup.

The Autofac wiki has some [good information on lifetime scopes here](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DeterministicDisposal).